# Create a bulit-in Like button

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using the Javascript SDK , and I can't create a built-in Like button. I read the following source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/

And it said to invoke this:

```
curl -X POST \
     -F 'access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
     -F 'object=OG_OBJECT_URL' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB ID]/og.likes
```

I really don't know how to use that in the JS SDK . I have intermediate knowledge with JS and PHP , but i never used that.

What can get me started with this?

Comment: The answer on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11315195/why-is-open-graph-built-in-like-not-working-anymore has a JS SDK example

Answer (score -1):

That just means to make a POST request with certain parameters/data in the body.  You can do that with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: No, you can – see not on the page you linked: _“Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.”_